# Can not add anntation to mapbox

Tags: dictionary, annotations, offline, mapbox

i can not add a annotation for offline map  .  help me thanks,

```
RMAnnotation *annotation = [RMAnnotation annotationWithMapView:mapView coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.293247,108.896141) andTitle:@"nohao"];
UIImage *flagImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Compass.png"];
annotation.userInfo = flagImage;
annotation.title=@"haha";
annotation.subtitle=@"what this";
annotation.annotationIcon=flagImage;
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your annotation is added ok. You can check by examining `mapView.annotations`. What you probably mean is that nothing is showing up on the map. You either need to use the `-[RMMapViewDelegate mapView:layerForAnnotation:]` method to return a valid layer (like an `RMMarker` or an `RMShape`) or else use a class that does this automatically like `RMPointAnnotation`.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/marker/